# Visual Studio isn't showing warnings for rules added in editorconfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I have attempted to add this rule to my editorconfig file in hopes that visual studio users without resharper will address issues they're causing by iterating through ienumerables too often ([CA1851](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1851))

I know that the editorconfig file is being picked up because when I change spacing rules or disable default warnings, those changes are reflected. However, I am not seeing anything as an inline warning or in the post-build warning list after adding this rule:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1851.severity = warning
```

Comment: Can you post some code of an example from your project that _should_ trigger this warning?

Comment: @TimothyG. There's an example here. This shows up with resharper/rider (default) but not in VS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1851

Comment: @TimothyG. could you confirm if it works for you or not?

Comment: Something must be off about this rule.  No matter what I've tried in a dummy project, I cannot get the IDE to display a warning or error for this particular rule.  I don't have Resharper, but I assume it is somehow more aware of this rule.  Perhaps it is a bug with Visual Studio somehow.

Comment: :( I feel validated at least. Thanks for confirming! I'll open an issue in github if I don't stumble upon anything in a few days. @TimothyG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule was only shipped with .NET 7, unfortunately. Microsoft has submitted a PR to update the documentation to add an "Introduced version" specifier in order to clearly reflect this.

Comment: I can't get this rule to work in .NET 7 either.